# MVC partial views, partial model, partial controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently i am investigating if MVC is the way to go for the new major version of our web application. We have an existing web application with webparts, dynamically rendered according to some user settings. Each webpart has its own data and own logic (for example, one webpart with user information, one webpart with currently logged-in users, one webpart with appointments etc. etc.).

What we need to accomplish (i think) is to render a single view, which contains several partial views. Each partial view represents a different model, and has its own logic.

I figured out how to put multiple partial views within a single view, but i don't know how to handle the business logic for each view (in "partial controllers"? if possible at al?), and handle the model for each view?

So the main purpose is to render a page with multiple dynamic views (according to what the user has configured), each with its own logic and data. And then when, for example, a button is clicked in a partial view, the corresponding controller is called to handle the event, and returns the updated partial view. The partial views need to be loosely coupled, and updated async.

From what i've seen so far the most tutorials and documentation are focussing on MVC in general, not on how to separete the business logic and model for eachr partial view.

So I'm not asking how to do this, but:

- Is it possible to easy accomplish this with MVC 4 or 5?
- Does anybody know a good real-life example or tutorial about this?

I hope anyone can point me in the right direction or share some thoughts on this...

Comment: Partial views are great if you have page with repetition, you can just have the markup written once. Like message posts etc. They are also useful if you have a lot of markup switching in and out with Javascript. Partial views access their data from the view model which is provided by the view hosting them. They do not have their own logic. You could have a view model with the data already stored and then render it in a partial view but the logic is not kept in the partial view. Logic work is done at the controller not the view.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. How about calling @Html.Action("MyAction","PartialController1") in my main view for each partial view that i want to render, and let all those small "partial" controllers do their own logic and return their own particular partial views, each with their own @model, is that best practice??

Comment: You don't have a partial controller, it would just be a controller you are calling to. There is nothing stopping you returning partial views by accessing controller actions. Your problem is the datatype the partial view uses is restricted by the view hosting the partial view. The only way I would see around it if you wanted it all done in partials is have each partial view calling its own javascript file, which can access and return data to populate it. It does mean your site is dependent on JS being turned on in browser though.

Comment: James, but in this small test i have written in the past hour, i strongly-type my parial views like this: @model IEnumerable<MvcTest.Models.UserInfo>, and display the data in the partial view like this: Html.DisplayFor(Model.First().UserName) etc. Could you please tell me what you mean with "the datatype the partial view uses is restricted by the view hosting the partial view" ???

Comment: In your partial view, the Username being used comes from the ViewModel passed in to your view `UserInfo`. So you are restricted in your partial views to the information passed in to the view. Each partial view does not have its own partial controller or its own Data Type. It is using the datatype of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

You could make one or more controllers with an action for each webpart.

Group all related webparts in the same controller but make an action and View+ViewModel for each webpart. Then use the Html.RenderAction method to call these actions (and have your webparts placed) on your page/main view.

DISCLAIMER: This said, each call to Html.RenderAction creates a complete mvc flow, instanciating a controller, model and view and finally renders the whole thing and passes the value to your page/main view. Having lots of Html.RenderAction has the potential to slow your page creation a lot. You could look into DI/IoC like Unity and consider reusing controllers, or just look into System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver to handle the creation of controllers yourself.